# Nunjucks nl2br does not exist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nl2br, nunjucks

I need a filter like the Jinja "nl2br", but in the Nunjucks.
In the documentation are a mention (https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html), but I searched it in the nunjucks code (https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/blob/master/src/filters.js) and it does not exist.

Somebody knows how to solve it with a equivalent filter or another solution? Or I need to create the filter?

Answer (score 6):

Nunjucks has built-in escaping. If you set `{autoescape: true}` when settings up Nunjucks, then you don't need to do anything. Otherwise, you can use the `escape` filter.

If you just want to escape newlines, then do this:

```
env.addFilter('nl2br', function(str) {
    return str.replace(/\r|\n|\r\n/g, '<br />')
})
```

and use the newly created `nl2br` filter.

Note: `env` is your Nunjucks environment.

Comment: I had already setted the autoscape like true, but not works. Only the escape filter doesn't work too. My solution was to create the filter and use it with the safe like it: {{description|nl2br|safe}}

Comment: @RenathoDeCarliRosa that's a bad idea, because it will allow any html/script to be intjected into the html

Answer (score 5):

There is now a `nl2br` filter in nunjucks (see the [documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#nl2br))

So i've yout got some unsafe text, but you still want to have new lines changed to `<br/>` tags, you can use the following example for the docs

```
{{ "foo\nbar" | striptags(true) | escape | nl2br }}
```

which will output

```
foo<br />\nbar
```

and be displayed as

foo
bar